# Encryption on cookie codeigniter 3.0.x

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, encryption

This is my first time using the encryption library. I have read the documentation and I have done some encryption on strings. I want to ask this time is this is a valid thing to do.

My code:

```
public function store_cookie($email){
    if($this->input->post('remember_me') == 'remember'){
        //try email later
        $cookie = array(
                'name'   => 'remember' ,
                'value'  => $email,
                'expire' => '86500',
                'prefix' => '',
                'secure' => FALSE
                );
        $this->input->set_cookie($this->encryption->encrypt($cookie));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right way to store the encrypted cookies, Encrypt the value(If necessary) not the entire cookies, Take a look on the codes below

```
public function store_cookie($email) {

    if($this->input->post('remember_me') == 'remember'){
        //try email later
        $cookie = array(
            'name'   => 'remember' ,
            'value'  => $this->encryption->encrypt($email),
            'expire' => '86500',
            'prefix' => '',
            'secure' => FALSE
        );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    }
}
```